# How do you disable the "Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price" on magento

Tags: magento-1.8

How do you disable the "Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price" on magento.

Comment: Have you got the answer of your query?

Answer (score 0):

> Manufacturer’s Suggested Retail Price

Some manufacturers may implement a so-called “minimum advertised price” restriction. It means that the retailers can’t promote the product below a fixed price. NOTE, that it is forbidden for the merchant only to DISPLAY the lower price, not to SELL the item for less. Thus, it makes sense to hide the product price and show it as soon as the item is already in the customer’s shopping cart.

> Minimum Advertised Price - Magento’s Built-in Option

Magento comes with a built-in Minimum Advertised Price (MAP) option. This is what will help the e-store owners to offer the better price to their customers without displaying it on the product page. Due to the fact that MAP can be configured at global and product levels, the retailer can apply the MAP settings to all products or only specific ones. Here’s how it works:

1. On the Admin Panel go to System>Configuration>Minimum Advertised
   Price tab;

[image]

2. Change Enable MAP to “Yes”;

At the Apply MAP (Default Value) section choose “No” (unless you want to hide all prices throughout your e-shop);

[image]

3. Now you can choose where you want to Display Actual Price:

   - In cart;
   - Before order confirmation;
   - On gesture (on click);
4. Once completed, click Save button.

Here’s how it looks on the frontend:

[image]

**I hope this will help, as far as I understand you ask for this**